# When exporting Map Service layer of USGS topo maps as a GeoTIFF the resolution is always fuzzy. How can I get a better image?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, usgs

Using QGIS. When I increase DPI the export times out. Image must be Georeferenced because I am bringing it into CAD with other data on State Plane coord. The individual 7.5" Quad JPEGS from the USGS topoview web application are very crisp and good image quality but they are not georeferenced properly.
The link I am streaming the MapServer from is:
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer
Any suggestions to get the best quality image from the MapServer layer?

Comment: Don't use the print export option to do this, down load the tiles and put them together with QGIS or gdal and transform them

Comment: @IanTurton I tried using Qtiles plugin to download tiles but they still are poor resolution and not crisp and clear like the jpeg quad maps. (I think it just creates tiles from Canvas display may not be retrieving data from source?) How do you download the tiles (from source (USGS)) so I can get full resolution?